# Adding query parameters to home URL resolves in 404 Angular 5

Tags: routes, angular5, angular-routing, query-string

I'm trying to add query parameters for some of the URLs for my app. I'm using the snapshot method and I have a function that adds the query parameters to the URLs. Everything works fine, except when I try to add query parameters to my Home URL, then my URL is picked up by

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found'}
```

and it is redirected to the NotFoundComponent.

The path for my HomeComponent is defined like:

```
{ path: ':language', component: HomeComponent}
```

The function is defined like:

```
this.router.navigate(['en'], {
    queryParams: {'param1': this.value1, 'param2': this.value2}
});
```

and I know that the function works because when I try to add the query parameters for some other component like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['en/other-component'], {
    queryParams: {'param1': this.value1, 'param2': this.value2}
});
```

there are no problems, I get redirected to the wanted page and the query parameters are passed to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If the first segment doesn't start with / it is a relative route. router.navigate needs a relativeTo parameter for relative navigation

```
this.router.navigate(['en'], {
    queryParams: {'param1': this.value1, 'param2':  this.value2},relativeTo: this.route
});
```

example:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: '' 
}) 
export class Component { 
  constructor(      
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {}

  goToEdit(person:Person) {
      this.router.navigate([ en ], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
}
```